# Django import models

Tags: django, import

OK -- I've been working with Django for a few months now and have come across a weird issue. To set it up, here's my webapp structure.

The main Django project is called `cpm`.
I have a bunch of django apps in the `cpm` folder. Within each app, I have my models.py file.

Now, when I want to create/use models from other apps I would do something like:

```
from cpm.products.models import *
```

assuming an app named `products` was present. Recently, I started to get some errors saying things like, `cannot import XYZ from products`. So, after much searching, I changed the line:

```
from cpm.products.models import *
```

to

```
from products.models import *
```

I just dropped the `cpm.` part and now it works.

Can someone tell me why this is happening? It seems to be happening on only portions of my apps (I have a bunch within the CPM project). I want to make sure my syntax is accurate as I move forward.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The project root's directory got removed from the python path somewhere along the way, or you removed the `__init__.py` file from it's root.

On a side note, importing `*` will lead to issues, especially when you start adding lots of apps.  Consider doing `from products import models as prod_models`.  Then doing `prod_models.MyModel` where you need to reference your models.

Comment: Interesting. I created a new app tonight (./manage startapp) and notice that there is a file __init.py__ in the directory that is not present in "older" app directories. Is this what you are referring to?
Thanks for the tip on the importing of models. I'll be sure to refine my code.